# VueRouter's beforeEach causes error: failed to convert exception to string

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My console says:

```
[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
<failed to convert exception to string>
```

The line that causes that error is the one in main.js:

```
next('/login')
```

my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import App from './App.vue'
import Routes from './routes'

import { store } from './store/store';


Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: Routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    next('/login');
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
  router: router,
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

My routes.js file:

```
export default [
    { path: '/', component: Game, cors: true },
    { path: '/login', component: Login },
    { path: '/signin', component: SignIn },
    { path: '/gamerouter', component: GameRouter },
    { path: '/waitingforplayers', component: WaitingForPlayers, name: "buba" },
    { path: '/selectPlayersForTeams', component: SelectPlayersForTeams },
    { path: '/startStatistics', component: StartStatistics },
    { path: '/gamelocked', component: GameLocked },
    { path: '/answering', component: Answering },

]
```

I also get this error if i put next('/'), but i do not get this error if i write next() or next(false);
Any ideas that might help me fix this?

Comment: Does it work if you directly write the routes inside your main.js file and are the Game and Login components working correctly?

Comment: All the components work correctly. Also if i make       this.$router.push('/Answering'); in any of components it redirects me correctly to component Answering.

Comment: Can you use a `try...catch` block around the `next()` and call `next(error)` inside the catch block. You should be able to print this error inside the `router.onError` callback https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-onerror

Comment: I did:
try {
 router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  next('/login')
 })
}
catch(err) {
 next(err)
}
router.onError((err) => { console.log("my error", err)})

But it gave me only: 
my error <failed to convert exception to string>

So nothing new:(

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in your console? You should be able to see the exception there

Comment: I never used breakpoints. Now i've read some docs to chrome dev tools, set a breakpoint on next('/login') but dont know what to do later.

Comment: You need to set the breakpoint on the `console.log("my error..)`. When the error occurs and breakpoint gets hit the execution is paused and if you then mouse-over the `err` variable you should be able to see what type of exception this is. You also have more information (like the call-stack) on the right side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178714/discussion-between-kalreg-and-puelo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` has to be called without parameters to confirm navigation, otherwise you will keep triggering the `beforeEach` hook:

```
router.beforeEach(function(to, from, next) {
  console.log(to.path)
  if (to.path !== '/timer') {
    next("/timer");
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, i found it out ten minutes ago. +1 for correct answer:-)